# Reverse iterator won't compile

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile a reverse iterator but my attempts to do so give a horrid mess. The minimal example of the code is...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class frag {
    public:
        void print (void) const;
    private:
        std::vector<int> a;
};

void frag::print (void) const
{
    for (std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator iter = a.begin ();
         iter                                   != a.end ();
         ++iter) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and attempting to compile it produces the following...

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algobase.h:69,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/char_traits.h:41,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ios:41,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.4/ostream:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream:40,
             from frag.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator.h: In constructor ‘std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::reverse_iterator(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iter>&) [with _Iter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >]’:
frag.cpp:14:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator.h:134: error: no matching function for call to ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::__normal_iterator(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >)’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator.h:686: note: candidates are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::__normal_iterator(const _Iterator&) [with _Iterator = int*, _Container = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator.h:683: note:                 __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::__normal_iterator() [with _Iterator = int*, _Container = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator.h:669: note:                 __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::__normal_iterator(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&)
```

There was a question on this subject yesterday but I don't think this is the same as it isn't a template. If a vector is declared in a similar way locally it is quite happy. (g++ on Ubuntu 10.4).

Anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use `const_reverse_iterator` (`print` is a `const` function so `a` is `const`) and `a.rbegin()` and `a.rend()` rather than `begin()` and `end()`.

Comment: dang, a couple minutes sooner :(

Comment: @rubenvb: Although my first attempt only spotted one issue, frantically edited to update with the second issue.

Comment: :D some questions just seem to attract the crowd, don't they?

Comment: Thank you. I tried it in my real program and that's fixed it.

Comment: +1 - you're fast! I think I need to write a bot or something to detect new questions and allow me to input answers faster. This site is like WoW with reputation points being like experience points, only more fun and less pointless.

Comment: "more fun and less pointless". Well, that's entirely a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Two things that may cause an issue in your code:

1. Your `print()` function is declared `const`, so you'll (probably need to or should) use a `const_reverse_iterator`.
2. You're creating a `reverse_iterator` from a `normal_iterator` (`std::vector<T>::begin()`)

Comment: In the second point the problem is not pointing at the last element, but assigning and comparing incompatible types `normal_iterator` and `reverse_iterator`

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign a *reverse* iterator to a reverse iterator. The same with comparison. Reverse iterators can be obtained using methods `rbegin` and `rend`:

```
for (std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator iter = a.rbegin(); iter != a.rend(); ++iter);
```

EDIT (for completeness)
As others have noticed, const_reverse_iterator will be necessary here as well.

Comment: Thank you; I hadn't actually made that mistake in the real program, but I was trying lots of things in the minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers already point out that a `const_reverse_iterator` with `rbegin`/`rend` is needed in this case.

In addition to that, a good practice would be to use `crbegin` or `crend` (introduced in C++11) to explicitly indicate you are requesting the const version of the iterator since the `print` function is const.